# Calculate gradient of Kronecker product.

Tags: vector-analysis, kronecker-product

Assume we have a matrix $M\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and two vectors $z\in \mathbb R^{n}$ and $p\in\mathbb R^{k}$. Then, define $\mathbb 1_{i\times j}$ is $i$-by-$j$ vector whose elements are all 1. $\otimes$ means the Kronecker operator.

How to calculate the gradient of this expression with respect to $z$?
$$
Mz \otimes \mathbb 1_{r\times 1} - \mathbb 1_{s\times1}\otimes p
$$
where $s = mr/k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the well-known Kronecker-vec formula
$${\rm vec}(ABC) = (C^T\otimes A)\,{\rm vec}(B)$$
the outer product of two vectors can be expanded in several equivalent ways
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(ab^T) &= {\rm vec}(ab^TI_b) = {\rm vec}(I_aab^T) \\
b\otimes a &= (I_b\otimes a)\,b = (b\otimes I_a)\,a \\
}$$
Apply this result to the current the function and calculate the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 y &= Mz\otimes{\tt1}_r - {\tt1}_s\otimes p \\
   &= (I_m\otimes{\tt1}_r)(Mz) - {\tt1}_s\otimes p \\
dy &= (I_m\otimes{\tt1}_r)M\,dz \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} &= (I_m\otimes{\tt1}_r)M \\
}$$